# How to "fake" a front-end object when running a Mathematica script?

Tags: front-end, scripting

I'm running a Mathematica script (content of which cannot be disclosed here) and some part of it requires "front-end"? Since it's running in a script, there is not one and it gave the following error:

```
FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.
```

How does one "fake" one so the program may run without error/problem like this?

Comment: See [`UsingFrontEnd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UsingFrontEnd.html) and make sure `DISPLAY` is set correctly.

Comment: I just don't know what the arguments are supposed to be. `echo $DISPLAY` on my Mac computer gives `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.6aaobKJfXJ/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`

Comment: Actually, instead of `UsingFrontEnd`, is it possible to set `$FrontEnd` to something at the beginning of my script, so whatever requires on can find it, but I won't need to find every command that possibly need one and wrap each of them with `UsingFrontEnd`, since I don't understand the code?

Comment: Wrapping all your code in just one `UsingFrontEnd[]` statement should be fine. No need to worry about `DISPLAY` on Mac.